# PHP Yii Date using Locale pt_BR

Tags: php, yii

Im trying to make php, using Yii framework, show `date()` in pt_br.

```
setlocale(LC_TIME,"pt_BR")
```

What Im doing wrong?

Comment: Not very clear question. In the index.php (in the root) you can set the timezone like so: date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");

Comment: Yii has its own date formatting methods, why are you using `date`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding following line in index.php so that it gets executed first before any other php code.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
```